# Is it possible to get the 'next meeting 'complication on top of the time-lapse watch face?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I was using the Utility face on my Apple watch and love the ability to tap the bottom and see my meetings.

[image]

The time-lapse faces are compelling, but I'm really missing the calendar complication.

[image]

I'd like to combine them.

My question is: **Is it possible to get the 'next meeting 'complication on top of the time-lapse watch face?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Watch OS 2.0 doesn't include a kit to make changes like that. You could get Xcode and make your own complication, but even registered developers don't get to make custom watch faces yet.

You'd need to be Hermès and work directly with Apple to get that done on iOS 9 and watch OS 2.